# Unitary Equivalence of Parity Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, hamiltonian, parity

I recently read a statement that 'parity operator is defined only up to unitary equivalence' in a paper about PT symmetric quantum mechanics. But I didn't understand the meaning of it.

It was regarding a Hamiltonian $H=p^2+x^2+2x$ which is apparently non PT symmetric but when expressed as

$H=p^2+(x+1)^2-1$ , it becomes PT symmetric about the point $x=-1$

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PT symmetry is a red herring here. Your hamiltonian is visibly T symmetric, so you are only trying to understand its P-symmetry properties. The momentum (kinetic) piece is invariant under the maneuvers to follow.

You want to understand how the two parity operators around 0 and -1 are related,
$$
P \hat x P = -\hat x ~; \qquad \tilde P (\hat x +1) \tilde P = - (\hat x+1) ~ .
$$

You appreciate that
$$
e^{i\hat p /\hbar } ~~\hat x~~ e^{-i\hat p /\hbar }= \hat x +1, ~~~\leadsto \\
\tilde P ~ e^{i\hat p /\hbar } ~\hat x~ e^{-i\hat p /\hbar }   ~ \tilde P= - e^{i\hat p /\hbar } ~\hat x~ e^{-i\hat p /\hbar }, ~~\implies \\
e^{-i\hat p /\hbar }~\tilde P ~ e^{i\hat p /\hbar } ~\hat x~ e^{-i\hat p /\hbar }   ~ \tilde P~ e^{i\hat p /\hbar } = -\hat x~ \leadsto \\
\tilde P = e^{i\hat p /\hbar }~P~e^{-i\hat p /\hbar }.
$$
That is, the two parity operators are unitarily equivalent. You may confirm the change has no bearing on parity reflections of $\hat p$, which you already know since the origin of a variable is invisible to its derivative.

You may now proceed to apply the $\tilde P T$ operator on your hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's much clear now.