# Is the parity transformation dependent on the choice of origin?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, parity

In quantum field theory, the parity-transformation takes a scalar $\phi(t, x)$ and sends it to $\phi(t, -x)$. (For example, Peskin and Schroeder, eq. $3.129$). This  transformation seems highly dependent on the choice of the origin. A different observer, with a different origin, would not see this as a parity transformation.

Is this correct ? and in that case where does this dependence come from
the original definition $P a_p P = \eta_a a_{-p}$ (P&S, $3.123$)does not seem to depend on origin (though it does depend on which boost is chosen).

This also makes the transformation seem less "fundamental", as it is so intimately tied to our frame of reference, is that right?

Comment: Hint: translational invariance

Comment: See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637831/unitary-equivalence-of-parity-operator).